# How can I make a page private with code login on php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a new website for a business I'd like to start and I got stuck in one of its pages. I actually want one page to be private unless you log in with a code, and I don't know how to deal with it.

I've thought of using PHP for comparing both login form pass and a MySQL pass uploaded by me before but I'm not really used to work with PHP so I get stuck on it every time I try it. Could anyone, please, suggest me a piece of code for making it private?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution to this is by filtering users with IP or login credentials,

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will help you in filtering IPs, so only IPs which you allow can access that page.